# Javascript caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined - Datatable on click

Tags: javascript, events, datatable

I defined 3 datatables, the behaviour that I need for my website is to click on a row on the first DT that filters data and render the 2nd. Same when I click on a row of the second, I am filtering a json and render a third DT.

Everything works good, the logic seems working but after a random number of click on the first DT I get this error

```
caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'event_id')
```

I tried several ways to handle the click, bind, unbind and none of them worked.

Here is my JS code

```
columns_error_list_DT = [{
    "data": "error_message"
  }, {
    "data": "error_type"
  }, {
    "data": "nb_errors"
  },
  {
    "data": "step"
  }, {
    "data": "step_at"
  }, {
    "data": "event_id_list"
  }
]

var table_first_DT = init_datatable(df_errors_json_filtered, columns_error_list_DT, $('#error_list_DT'))

$('#first_DT tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {

  var second_DT = $('#error_details_DT').DataTable()
  second_DT.clear().draw();
  second_DT.destroy();

  var third_DT = $('#event_details_DT').DataTable()
  third_DT.clear()
  third_DT.destroy()

  var data_one = table_first_DT.row(this).data();
  $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
  var df_errors_details_json_filtered = df_errors_details_json['data'].filter(d => data_one['event_id_list'].includes(d['event_id']))

  columns_error_details_DT = [{
      "data": "event_id"
    }, {
      "data": "timestamp"
    },
    {
      "data": "operation_id"
    }, {
      "data": "amount"
    }, {
      "data": "iban"
    }, {
      "data": "specific_data_1"
    }, {
      "data": "specific_data_2"
    }, {
      "data": "specific_data_3"
    }, {
      "data": "specific_data_4"
    }
  ]

  var table_second_DT = init_datatable(df_errors_details_json_filtered, columns_error_details_DT, $('#error_details_DT'))

  $('#second_DT tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {

    var third_DT = $('#event_details_DT').DataTable()
    third_DT.clear()
    third_DT.destroy()

    var data = table_second_DT.row(this).data();
    $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');

    var df_event_details_json_filtered = df_event_details_json['data'].filter(d => data['event_id'] == d['event_id'])
    columns_event_details_DT = [{
      "data": "event_id"
    }, {
      "data": "step"
    }, {
      "data": "timestamp"
    }, {
      "data": "operation_id"
    }, {
      "data": "amount"
    }, {
      "data": "fee_amount"
    }, {
      "data": "iban"
    }, {
      "data": "operation_id"
    }, {
      "data": "specific_data_1"
    }, {
      "data": "specific_data_2"
    }, {
      "data": "specific_data_3"
    }, {
      "data": "specific_data_4"
    }, {
      "data": "specific_data_5"
    }]

    var event_details_DT = init_datatable(df_event_details_json_filtered[0].event_steps, columns_event_details_DT, $('#event_details_DT'))

  });
});
```

and the
function `init_datatable`:

```
function init_datatable(json_data, columns, element) {

  return element.DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "retrieve": true,
    "scrollY": "400px",
    "scrollX": true,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "fixedColumns": true,
    "data": json_data,
    "columns": columns,
    "language": {
      "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page",
      "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
      "info": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
      "infoEmpty": "No records available",
      "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
    }
  });
}
```

any ideas ? Ty

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: What is the value of `df_errors_details_json['data']`? It sounds like the array includes an `undefined` value.

Comment: @Bramar the lines happens sometimes at   '''var df_errors_details_json_filtered = df_errors_details_json['data'].filter(d => data_one['event_id_list'].includes(d['event_id']))'''  and sometimes on     '''var df_event_details_json_filtered = df_event_details_json['data'].filter(d => data['event_id'] == d['event_id'])'''
It depends on the order of the rows I clicked. I click on the first DT several times,no error and then on the second to make the third appears and the error pops

Comment: Yes it sounds like the array undefined value or not the matching value, problem is that I debugged it and the json is well filtered, and the the telescoping mechanism works fine to make the second DT filtered appear than the third. I supposed the error comes from the click event

Comment: Use triple backticks, not triple quotes, to put code in comments.

Comment: Please edit the question and show a sample value of `df_error_details_json.data`.